# Make [tezos-node] a synonym of [node]

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have the tags [node](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/node) and [tezos-node](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tezos-node) on Tezos. Both tags refer to a node in Tezos. Because they mean *exactly* the same thing, I think we should make one a synonym of the other. It would probably be better to make [tezos-node](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tezos-node) the one remapped to [node](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/node) because we really don't need to prefix "node" with "tezos". The name of the site makes it pretty clear it's referring to a Tezos node, and if there's confusion we can make a tag wiki.

Shall we make [tezos-node](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tezos-node) a synonym of [node](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/node)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree. This has been done now.

Comment: So, question should be tagged with feature-request and status-completed rather than discussion as the request has been completed.

Comment: @double-beep I agree it should have [status-completed], but [the discussion tag is generally what's used for tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work/70718#70718) since it's not really proposing an additional feature or change to an existing one, it's more discussing if something should be done or not.